# Regex is not matching given input

Tags: regex

I want to capture Any strings that starts with NC or VSS or Contains _5 or Ends with _2 . below is the one I built but for some reason its not working

```
^(NC|VSS)(_5)+(_2)$
```

for input `CLKOUT_SRC_N_2` it is not matching despite it ending in _2.
I changed the Reg Ex to `^(NC|VSS)|(_5)+|(_2)$` then `CLKOUT_SRC_P_5` is matching. Here _5 is at the end of string. how do I modify the string if I need `_5` to be somewhere in the middle of string as my prob statement says not at the end?

Answer (score 2):

Based in the examples and explanation you gave, I came up with the following regex:

`(^(NC|VSS)|.+(_5).+|(_2)$)`

It works accordingly: https://regex101.com/r/SHFJhG/1

> how do I modify the string if I need _5 to be somewhere in the middle
> of string...

I've added a `.+` just after and before the `(_5)`, so it guarantees that we should have at least one character before and after a occurrence of `_5`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, you may use:

```
^(?:NC|VSS)|(?<!^)_5(?!$)|_2$
```

**[Demo](https://rextester.com/tester/AYCUDM41518)**.

**Breakdown:**

- `^(?:NC|VSS)` - Match either "NC" or "VSS" at the beginning of the string.
- `(?<!^)_5(?!$)` - Match "_5" that is neither at the beginning nor at the end of the string.
- `_2$` - Match "_2" at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can surround the `_5` with 2 dots so that there should be at least a character (the dot matches any character except a newline) to the left and the right, and use an alternation `|` to separate the matches.

```
^(NC|VSS)|.(_5).|(_2)$
```

The pattern matches

- `^(NC|VSS)` Capture either `NC` or `VSS` in group 1 at the start of the string
- `|` Or
- `.(_5).` Capture `_5` in group 2 surrounded by a dot so that it can not be at the start or at the end of the string
- `|` Or
- `(_2)$` Capture `_2` in group 3 at the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v2hIju/1)

Comment: Doesn't this need a + after the . to ensure that there is at least one occurrence of _5 in the middle of the string?

Comment: No the dot itself is enough to make sure it is not at the end